# Make tabular span textwidth exactly

Tags: tables

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  A & B & \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In the output:
[image]

the last column goes out of the bounds of the page. I could constrain the last column by using`\begin{tabular}{llp{3cm}}`. However, it would be more convenient to make the table span textwidth automatically. How to do it?

Comment: `tabularx` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: you should use table with prescribed width. for example `tabular*` with `p` column type  or `tabularx`.

Comment: @Zarko, could you please provide an elaborate answer?

Answer (score 1):

with `tabularx` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}             % <---
\usepackage{lipsum}

\noindent
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llX}  % table width is determined with \linewidth
                                   % at least one column had to be `X` type
  A & B & \lipsum[66]
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} llX @{}} % border \tabcolsep is suppressed
  A & B & \lipsum[66]
\end{tabularx}

\begin{table}[htb]                      % table is in float environment
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}llX@{}} % border \tabcolsep is suppressed
  A & B & \lipsum[66]
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]